# How do I make external CMake project headers available for code navigation in Xcode?

Tags: c++, cmake

I have a CMake project set up in the following way...

```
root
└CMakeLists.txt
└src
   └CMakeLists.txt
   └mysource.cpp
└3rd
   └dependency
      └CMakeLists.txt
      └include
         └someheader.hpp
```

The directory `3rd` contains dependencies that are included in `root/CMakeLists.txt` using `add_subdirectory()`. So:

```
add_subdirectory(3rd/dependency)
```

And later linked with:

```
target_link_libraries(${target} dependency)
```

My problem is that (for obvious reasons) none of the third-party headers are included in the generated Xcode project.

Therefore code navigation does not work correctly. If my project includes `3rd/dependency/include/someheader.hpp` and I ctrl-cmd-click to Jump To Definition. Nothing happens.

How do I tell CMake to include these headers in the project?

Comment: It should just work, you might need to build first to make it work?